# Kivy: how to properly make a label rezise in recycleview

Tags: python, kivy, resize, label

I'm trying to build a log viewer on kivy using recycleview since logs can be pretty large. I'm assigning one label widget per line so I can have more control over the text in the future. Some lines will have more text than others so adapted the Label widget to resize according, but when putting that inside recycleview can't seem to be able to control the height of the widget per line anymore, it stays at the same size. What I expect is the label to wrap on the text and adjust height since don't need the extra space between lines. If there's to little text a lot of free space is shown, if I put to much text in the label it floods and label doesn't grow.

One workaround that I tried with different code was to assign at least a 200 lines per label, that seems to work, but I do need more control over each line of text.

This is the example code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<Row@BoxLayout>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5 #Red Marker
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: root.value
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        font_size: 20

<LogDisplayWidget>:
    rv: rv
    orientation: 'vertical'
                
    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
        bar_width: dp(10)
        viewclass: 'Row'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: dp(2)
''')


class LogDisplayWidget(BoxLayout):
    rv = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self):
        super(LogDisplayWidget, self).__init__()
        self.load_text()

    def load_text(self):
        for i in range(10):
            line = str(i) + 'This is a test of a bunch of text'
            self.rv.data.append({'value': line})


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LogDisplayWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSgxf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdYYY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Did a code rewrite, the labels appear resized correctly in first page, but getting jerky unexpected results after scrolling, it shows correct label size sometimes then some are to big, and the scroll skips like trying to adjust itself and it fixes size again. Does anyone have a better way to implement this or I'm missing something? I'm suspecting it has something to do with the way the view refreshes

This is the new code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
import random

Builder.load_string('''
<Row@Label>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5 #Red Marker
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    text_size: self.width, None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    font_size: dp(20)

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Row'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(20)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(3)
        
''')


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        line = ''
        for i in range(50):
            n = random.randint(0, 1)
            if n:
                j = random.randint(5, 30)
                line = 'Line: ' + str(i+1) + ' This is a test of a bunch of text' * j
            else:
                line = 'Line: ' + str(i+1) + ' This is a test of a bunch of text'
            self.data.append({'text': line})


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```